# Letting a Non-VPN-capable device go through my computer, it's VPN to the internet to connect to a remote host

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a problem with my network here. I have a base station of a MDA here which I need to connect through a VPN to a remote host to get data, so basically like this:

Base --- VPN --- Host

Since the Base Station is unable to make a VPN connection itself, I have a thin client (connected to the internet via WiFi) which shares it's VPN connection via LAN to a switch and the base station connected to the switch like this:

Base --- Switch --- PC --- WLAN --- Internet --- VPN --- Host

But that does not work. So, my question is, how do I let the Base Station communicate to the Host using my Thin Client?
I have full access to any component in this situation, except for the VPN and the Host.

Comment: he base will be forwarding all traffic to the default gateway which I suspect isnt your thin client. You need to add a default route pointing towards the VPN. Can you do so on the MDA? If not, it'll need to lease from the PC not the router on site.

Comment: I can't do so on the MDA. How would I do it on the PC?

Comment: Actually, if you're using ICS already then it should be DHCPing from the thin client already. Can you confirm if the MDA is leasing an IP outside the range being used by the PC for its wireless link?

Comment: It's using a different range, yes.

Comment: Bridging the TAP/TUN adapter and the Ethernet Adapter should cause all MDA traffic to travel over the VPN and hit the host. Only problem I forsee is if it looks for a DNS name not an IP.